# How to recover lost Thumbnail and preview options?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo T500 with Gnome desktop.

I have to upload photos daily for work and 2 weeks ago lost thumbnails and the ability to select preview. I assume an update did 'something'. Settings are correct to show thumbnails always and I've increased the size, but all I get are miniature boxes in my upload window.

Frustrating having to right down jpeg numbers and go from there...

Comment: Have you tried deleting the thumbnails to force a redraw? `rm -rf ~/.thumbnails` Then try to restart.

Comment: Writing [Solved] doesnt mark the question as answered . To mark it answered see http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally sorted it! I tried the suggestions you offered but to no avail so just moved on and put up with it, but have just now realised that it is OPERA that is causing all the problems. It recently stopped recognising my gmail accounts and I switched back to firefox....  photo uploads are just fine now with visible thumbnails!

Many thanks to you both for your suggestions.

Geoff

Comment: Please click **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How are you uploading your pics? Via a browser, from file-manager? If it would help, I will give you some solutions which might help you *see and upload* them:

- Open synaptics packet manager and install **ffmpegthumbnailer**, **ffmpegthumbs**.
  Now you may clean your already saved thumbnails by typing in to terminal: **`rm -rf ~/.thumbnails`**. Most file-manager could use these modules to build thumbnails!
- Use **Dolphin** file manager for more flexibility. It is far advanced in handling thumbnails and previews compared to nautilus, pcmanfm, thunar etc. you can install it from synaptics.
- Install an add-on in firefox if you're uploading pics to a particular website like photobucket, imgur etc.
- Finally, you may try some small python or bash scripts which will do the batch uploading automatically. If the above methods fails, you could go this way.